# How to make network loads after (or parallel to) graphics on boot

Tags: systemd, boot

I want to speed up my boot. I checked `systemd-analyze critical-chain` output:

```
graphical.target @13.691s
└─multi-user.target @13.691s
  └─cups-browsed.service @13.690s
    └─org.cups.cupsd.service @13.419s +269ms
      └─network.target @13.412s
        └─dhcpcd@enp6s0.service @5.850s +7.561s
          └─basic.target @5.838s
            └─sockets.target @5.838s
              └─avahi-daemon.socket @5.838s
                └─sysinit.target @5.837s
                  └─systemd-update-done.service @5.828s +8ms
                    └─ldconfig.service @5.183s +643ms
                      └─local-fs.target @5.180s
                        └─run-mount-extra.mount @3.333s +1.846s
                          └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-abd2e996\x2db30b\x2d4e55\x2db52e\x2dccd74242221a.service @1.650s +1.680s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @1.649s
                              └─lvm2-monitor.service @216ms +1.432s
                                └─lvm2-lvmetad.service @235ms
                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @207ms
                                    └─-.mount @181ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @207ms
                                        └─...
```

`dhcpcd@enp6s0.service` takes 7 seconds. But I don't really need network on the first seconds of my boot and can wait for a few seconds after WM start. What should I change to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, I would propose to identify in which target you are booting in:

```
systemctl list-units --type target

systemctl get-default
```

and you can experiment in which target you would like to boot.

Then, what I prefer to do, is to **disable** services that I do not need in boot phase and **start** them via @reboot in **cron**.

To give a simple example from a virtual machine:

```
# systemctl status iptables | grep disabled
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

# systemctl status ip6tables | grep disabled
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ip6tables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
```

```
# crontab -l
@reboot systemctl restart iptables
@reboot systemctl restart ip6tables
```

But be careful as systemd supports service dependencies and if you disable a core service, your system may not boot in a proper manner.

Comment: It looks a bit hacky, but it's better than nothing. Thanks